# Обработчик addEventListener в цикле

Tags: javascript, циклы, замыкания, userjs

Дано: javascript (userjs)
Куча функций типа btn0, btn1
Куча кнопок с id=bt0, bt1

Есть рабочий код, но его иного. Надо бы его в цикл загнать, ибо кнопок надо добавлять всё больше и больше, и не хочется раздувать юзер-скрипт.

```
document.getElementById('bt0').addEventListener("click", btn0, false);
document.getElementById('bt1').addEventListener("click", btn1, false);
document.getElementById('bt2').addEventListener("click", btn2, false);
```

То, что дело в замыкании - уже понял. Никак не пойму, как это реализовать...

Comment: вот я тут как мог подробно описал http://hashcode.ru/questions/272864#272867

Comment: for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
    document.getElementById('bt'+i).addEventListener("click", btn(i), false);
    }
    function btn(i) {
        return function() {
                  //то что было в btn
                }
    }

Comment: @eicto, спасибо. Сейчас буду думать ))
"то что было в btn"
Функции типа btn() - все разные. У каждой своё назначение и своя реакция - их не загнать в одни цикл.
Мне бы просто указать, что для кнопки с id0 будет работать btn0(),
для кнопки с id1 будет работать своя (не похожая на предыдующую) функция btn1()

Comment: и как вы предполагаете это оптимизировать ? Вообще вы можете массив функций сделать чтобы поменьше писать.... типа `var handlers=[btn0,btn1,btn2,...]`
и потом в цикле простом повесить типа

    document.getElementById('bt'+i).addEventListener("click", handlers[i], false);

но по моему вам надо задуматься об архитектуре приложения.

Comment: в идеале бы 

    for(var j=0; j<totalBtns; j++){
    document.getElementById('bt'+j).addEventListener('click', btn+j+(), false);
    }
Но оно, ясное дело, не работает.

А про массив функций - похоже то, что я искал... Я уже и document.getElementById в массив запихал. Лишь бы работало.

Архитектуру, к сожалению, не поменять. Всё, что я могу сделать для удобства работы себя и 20 коллег, это юзер-скрипт, который будет крутиться в браузерах и изменять (улучшать) эргономику нашего веб-приложения...

Comment: методы можно в объекте так вызывать

    var handlers= {
        btn1: function(){},
        btn2: function(){}
    }
    ... {
    document.getElementById('bt'+i).addEventListener("click", handlers['bt'+i], false);
    }

ну я имел ввиду архитектуру js приложения. в смысле обычно не требуется писать миллион функций прямо

Comment: А у нас надо... Типовых задач, выполняемых нашим отделом всё больше и больше. А веб-морду не поменять. Вот для упрощения работы создаю кучу кнопок и навешиваю на каждую по типовой задаче.
Интересное решение. Работало бы внутри цикла... Сейчас попробую. Спасибо!
А то до конца смены ещё 3.5 часа, а мысли по реализации уже закончились ))

Comment: Вместо добавления к заголовку вопроса слова `Решено`, следует принять правильный ответ. Для этого надо нажать галочку рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 0):

1. Лучше использовать классы.
2. Еще лучше не добавлять события в цикле, а использовать делегирование http://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Comment: как я понял, ТС это не подходит ибо "(по сути каждая btn - это набор функций, повешенных на ту или иную кнопку)". Так что в данном случае как раз id(ТС кажется говорил что само приложение не может менять, поэтому классы тоже он не может сделать) и массив/объект с функциями.

Comment: @eicto http://jsfiddle.net/art3L/